# Navbar Sitting to low

Tags: css, html, image, nav

I have a simple navbar on my website using just HTML and CSS.  The navbar looks and functions like it should but there is a space between an image and the actual navbar.  I want the navbar to sit right below the image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>
    CrossFit Villains
    </title>
</head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

<body>
    <header>
        <span class="title">
            <a href="crossfitvillains.com">CrossFit Villains</a>
        </span>
        <br />
        <span>1702 McAra Street, Regina, SK</span>
        <br />
        <br />
    </header>

    <div id="banner">
        <img src ="banner.jpg" />
    </div>

    <nav>
        <ul id="menu" class="black">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Daily News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Class Sign In</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>



body {
background-image:url('dark_leather.png');
font-family: arial;
color: white;
margin-left: 15%;
}

.title {
font-size: 90px;
font-family: "Space Ranger";

text-decoration: none;
}

#address {
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

#email {
text-decoration: none;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
color: grey;
}

#container {
float:left; 
vertical-align: top;
}


.image-section{
float:left;
padding: 0 10px;
}

.cb{
clear: both;
}

.image-title {
padding-left: 50px;
}

footer {
padding-left: 10px;
color: white;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}

#footertext {
margin-left: 15%;
}

#menu {
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 50px 0;
padding: 0 0 0 10px;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 13px;
background: #eee;
height: 40px;
width: 1280px;
border-top: 2px solid #eee;
border-left: 2px solid #eee;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#menu li {
float: left;
margin: 0;
}

#menu li a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 0 20px;
line-height: 40px;
color: #666;
}

#menu li a:hover, #menu li.active a {
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
color: #999;
}

#menu.black {
border-top: 2px solid #333;
border-left: 2px solid #333;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
background: #333;
}
#menu.black a {
color: #CCC;
}

#menu.black li a:hover, #menu.black li.active a {
color: #999;
background: #555;
border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a css reset? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a jsFiddle based on the html and css you created [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EM2Rn/).

I ended up killing the extra pixels your `#banner` div had by writing:

```
#menu { margin: 0; }
#banner { line-height: 0; }
```

---

Edit:
As Benjamin stated above, if you want to keep your bottom margin, you can write:

```
#menu { margin: 0 0 50px 0 }.
// The order of specification is top, right, bottom, left
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your CSS needs a reset. Try the following.

```
applet, object, iframe,body,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym,       address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong,  sub, sup, tt, var,dd, dl, dt, li, ol, ul,fieldset, form, label, legend, caption,img, header,    section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline:none;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The unordered list in your nav has a 50px margin on top and bottom. That's what's separating your logo div from the nav.

```
#menu {
...
margin: 50px 0;
...
}
```

If you want 50px below, you'd want to write it:

```
margin: 0 0 50px 0;
```

or just:

```
margin-bottom: 50px;
```

You don't need a CSS reset. That's like using a cannon to do a scalpel's work.